# Simply tag-based highlighting with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I got this code which works:

```
    <html>

    <head>

    <title>JS highlighting test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function highlight()
    {
            var t = document.getElementById('highlight').innerHTML;

            t = t.replace(/(if|switch|for|while)\s*(\()/gi, "<b>$1</b>$2");
            document.getElementById('highlight').innerHTML = t;
    }

    </script>

    </head>

    <body onload="javascript:highlight();">

    <pre id="highlight">
    1  if(foo) {
    2          bar();
    3  }
    4
    3  while(--baz) {
    5          oof();
    6  }
    </pre>

    </body>

    </html>
```

I would like to have it for all `<pre>` tags instead of just one with some specific and
unique id as it works now. The best would be to have an combination of a specific tag
with a specific id. Is it possible to extend the small JS function above to work this
way (using some `document.getElementsByTag(tag).getElementsById(id).innerHTML` or
something alike (I don't know what exactly suites the need) in a loop? I tried myself but with no real success. I need only as simple solution as possible, nothing really special.

Thank you for your ideas.

--
nkd

Answer (score 2):

You almost guessed it right ;-)

```
function doSomethingWithAllPres() { 
    var pres = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
    for (var i = 0; i < pres.length; i++) { 
        // you can check the class name via pres[i].className === "highlight"
        // (and you should use a class instead of an id therefore)
        if (pres[i].className.indexOf("highlight") >= 0) {
            // action goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Using a JS-Framework like jQuery, things would be even more simple:

```
$("pre.highlight").each(function(i) {
    // action goes here
});
```

However, using a framework might be overkill...

Comment: I tried this:

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function highlight() {
                var pres = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");

                for (var i = 0; i < pres.length; i++) {
                        var h = pres[i].innerHtml;
                        h = h.replace(/if/gi, "<b>if</b>");
                        pres[i].innerHtml = h;
                }
        }

        </script>

But it does not work, why?

The problem is I got NO idea how to get the replaced content back to the appropriate pre tag when working with the array. That's exactly the problem I got.

Comment: Use innerHTML instead of innerHtml and it will work (be sure to replace both...)

Comment: Fantastic! It works. But, what to do to combine the pre tag condition with the "highlight" id condition? I tried 'document.getElementsByTagName("pre").getElementsById("highlight")' which does not work for me.

Comment: So you want all `pre` s and the element with the `id` "highlight"?  If you refactor the actual highlight code into a function (e.g. function highlightNode(node){...}), you can call that for every pre and the highlight element.  Check to make sure highlight isn't a `pre` so you don't do it twice on the same node.

Comment: I added this aspect to my answer in the meantime... you should apply a class (not an id) and you can check whether a pre has this class or not easily inside the loop (however you should be aware that a valid classname could also look like `classA hihglight` so you probably should use a more sophisticated test than ===).

Comment: Looks very difficult to me at the moment (this is my first JS code ever). :)

Comment: One last edit to clarify... Now the code applies to all pres wich have the class `highlight` ;-) Now, don't you forget to accept an anwser ;P

Comment: Too early. Hm, it seems the trick with className.indexOf does not work at all.

Comment: Sorry, a "CLASS" name, not "ID"! :) My fault. Everything works now. Thank you very much for fast and good response.